# Differences in getters method get and Object.defineProperty - Javascript

Tags: javascript, getter

So I'm working with the get method in objects and am wondering if there is a fundamental difference in its method compared to Object.defineProperty

With get I can define and modify a property within an object.

```
var objectOne = { a:1, get b() { return this.a + 1 };
```

Now I have a:1 and b:2 But if I wrote simply

```
var objectOne = { a:1};
```

I have {a:1} and then can define or modify with

```
Object.defineProperty(objectOne, "b",{ get: function() { this.a + 1; } });
```

Obsviously defineProperties for multiple properties. But besides the difference of using Object.defineProperty after an object has been made and get when an object is being created is there anything else that is involved in these separate methods?

Comment: With `Object.defineProperty`, the `enumerable` and `configurable` attributes of the property will default to `false` for newly created properties.

Comment: @Teemu: Sure, but accessor properties (with `get` and `set`) don't have a `writable` attribute :-)